# Seeing a lot of posts from one user in LQP queue

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

Earlier today while reviewing the Low Quality Posts queue I noticed a lot of posts from a single 6K user. Some of these posts are recent ones, some are up to 7 years old. Some of the posts are not great but I wouldn't consider them Low Quality either.

Is this accumulation of posts from one user a coincidence or is there something fishy going on?

Here's a list of the reviews: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24563980), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24563981), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24563985), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24563988), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24564025), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24564026), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24564028), [8](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24564094), [9](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24564098), [10](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24564155), [11](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24564156), [12](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24564240), [13](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24564247), [14](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24564249)

Comment: Nothing that would need additional actions by community members to deal with. It's likely some form of revenge... flagging? you can see in their profile how they've recently been hit with a bunch of downvotes (followed by a correction)

Comment: Today in new and creative ways to get in trouble with a moderator...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a coincidence.

One user apparently went through that other user's post history and raised flags on all of those answers.

That is…not the recommended way to use flags. It veers *dangerously* close to "targeting" of that user. The only arguably redeeming factor is that flags are meant to be confidential (except, of course, for the leaky abstraction that is the review queues).

Either way, **please evaluate each post that you see appear in the review queues on its own merits**. The author of a post shouldn't even be relevant. I don't pay attention to it when handling moderator flags.

Comment: What about the serial downvotes ? https://stackoverflow.com/users/62282/chev?tab=reputation&sort=time

Comment: One set of serial downvotes has already been reversed automatically by the script, @ankii. There may be another set remaining to be reversed within the next 24 hours.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for clarifying. I never evaluate posts on the author and usually I don't look at the author either.  It was more the visual of the avatar and the badges which struck me. I skipped most of those reviews anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray since the cause was in fact some targeting, what should I do if I see something like that again - bring it to meta, mod-flag or just ignore?

Comment: This was a pretty obvious case. I think you knew it was targeting. A moderator flag makes the most sense in that case, since there's really nothing the community can or should do about it. @Thomas